# General solution for an improper node (ODE).

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

This might be a really simple question.

Define $A=\begin{bmatrix}a&1\\0&a\end{bmatrix}$, $a\neq 0$; the eigenvalue $a$ has only one real associated eigenvector $v$ and then $\phi_1(t)=e^{at}v$ is a solution of the ODE $$\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax,$$ but in order to find the general solution, I need one more linearly independent solution.

> Is there a "satisfactory" way to obtain it?

To explain the word "satisfactory", I've read somewhere that if $w\in \mathbb{R^2}$ is linearly independent of $v$, then $\phi_2(t):=e^{at}(w+tv)$ is the solution I seek, but the author didn't give further explanation (probably because anyone should be able to figure out where this came from) and I got confused.

Writing $Aw=v+\beta w$, the matrix of $x\rightarrow Ax$ in the base $\{v,w\}$ is $\begin{bmatrix}a&1\\0&\beta\end{bmatrix}$, but since the eigenvalues are invariant on representation, $\beta=a$ and $Aw=v+aw$, then $$\frac{d}{dt} \phi_2=ae^ {at}(w+tv)+e^{at}v=e^{at}(atv+aw+v)=A(w+tv)=A\phi_2$$ that is, $\phi_2(t)$ is indeed a solution and there's something very clever about it that makes me think it makes sense, but it is still not a solution I could get on my own.

> Can anyone explain the meaning of this choice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write $A$ as the sum of a diagonal and nilpotent matrix and expand $e^{tA}$ exponential using the power series for the exponential. You’ll see that it simplifies nicely.

Comment: Thank you! I got something like $e^{tA}=e^{ta}(E+tE_1)$, where $E$ is the identity and $E_1$ is the nilpotent matrix. I'm starting to get worried, because it feels like your hint gave me the answer, but I still don't understand very well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @amd suggested, we can write $A = D + N$ where 
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}a&0\\0&a\end{bmatrix}, \; N = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then for $t\in\mathbb R$ we have
\begin{align}
e^{tA} &= e^{t(D+N)}\\
&= e^{tD}e^{tN}\\
&= \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tD)^n}{n!}\right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(tN)^n}{n!}\right)\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}e^{ta}&0\\0&e^{ta}\end{bmatrix}  \begin{bmatrix}1&t\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}e^{ta}&te^{ta}\\0&e^{ta}\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Given $x^0\in\mathbb R^2$ we have
$$ 
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt} \left[e^{tA}x^0\right] = Ae^{tA}x^0, 
$$
and so $e^{tA}x$ is a solution to the ODE $\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt} x = Ax$. If $x=\begin{bmatrix} v\\ w \end{bmatrix}$ then
\begin{align}
e^{tA}x &= \begin{bmatrix}e^{ta}&te^{ta}\\0&e^{ta}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} v\\ w \end{bmatrix}\\
 &= \begin{bmatrix} e^{ta}(v+tw)\\we^{ta}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}
from which we conclude.

Comment: Ah, I see. I should've written it 'till the end after he gave me the hint! Thanks a lot to you and @amd.